# Irrelevant Baked texture maps

Tags: texturing, uv, baking

So I built procedural textures along with actual textures.
Every thing is properly UV unwrapped too!
[image: Procedural textures]

However, when I bake the diffuse texture, it looks messed up like this[image]

What am I possibly messing up with?
Requested Blend file
[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ijDsU-znC-XKJOF70NQkXyBl7Hi10LQ)

Comment: PS: There are three slots used up for the material, for the concrete, for bricks, and interior walls, assigned to the respective faces of the polygon

Comment: [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/166349/edit) details directly into question.

Comment: Some simplified (one problematic face) blend file would be helpful, screens does not tell so much here. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ijDsU-znC-XKJOF70NQkXyBl7Hi10LQ this is the blend file

Comment: Do you guys think it could be something related to the mapping node i used to scale up the UV textures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Blender SE forums :)

You have three materials mapped to same UV space, so before you bake you need to tell Blender to bake each of those materials to the same image. (3 materials all baked to the same image).

To do that ......

1: In the UV editor Create a new image to bake to. In the screenshots below I named this image **3 material bake**. save this Image to your hard drive.

2: Select one of the three materials.

In the Node Editor add a new **Image Texture**.
In this new node load up the image that was create in the UV editor. Leave this new node *unconnected* but *selected*! (Very important to leave it selected).

Select the second material and repeat (Add new Image Texture and load up same image to bake to as was done for the first material and leave it selected).

Repeat for third material.
[image]

3: In the 3D editor, Object mode select the model.
   Hit that Bake button.

All three materials should now be baked correctly    to the image that was created in step 1.
[image]

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks a lot mate. So that's what I was missing. I had to add the image texture to all the other slots as well. Really solved my issue. Thanks a lot, it saved me 6 hours worth of work